# Double ref loop variable changing on loop update

Tags: c, pointers

After much head scratching I think I've spotted the issue.  The code:

```
struct Block {
    union {
        void* address;
        Block* next;
    };
    size_t size;
};


void* FragmentedMemoryManager::allocate(size_t size) {
if(allocationCount == maxAllocations) return nullptr;
Block** prev = &head;
Block* curr = head;
for(;
    curr != nullptr;
    prev = &curr,
    curr = curr->next
)
{
    if(curr->size < size) {
        continue;
    }
    Block allocBlock = Block{
        address: curr,
        size: size
    };
    allocations[allocationCount++] = allocBlock;
    size_t newSize = curr->size - size;
    //pretty sure this will wrap if it goes 'negative'
    assert(newSize < curr->size);
    //curr was completely allocated
    if(newSize == 0) {
        *prev = curr->next;
    } else {
        void* newAddress = toPtr(toUPtr(curr) + size);
        Block* newBlock = reinterpret_cast<Block*>(newAddress);
        newBlock->next = curr->next;
        newBlock->size = newSize;
        if(*prev == head) {
            *prev = newBlock;
        } else {
            //I know that this fails because prev is a double ref,
            //updating curr in the loop unintentionally updates prev
            //see line 36
            (*prev)->next = newBlock;
        }
    }
    std::sort(
        allocations, allocations + allocationCount, 
        [](Block a, Block b) 
    {
        return a.address < b.address;
    });
    memset(allocBlock.address, 0, size);
    return allocBlock.address;
}
return nullptr;
}
```

I'm convinced the idea is correct in that I need to do (*prev)->next = newBlock, I don't know how to preserve the intended reference of prev while also updating curr.  How do I do this?

The indention came out wonky.  Since there's a bit more going on here than just adding onto a list.  There's a possiblity of prev jumping completely over curr, essentially "deleting" curr.  I'm writing the nodes directly into the unallocated regions of memory.

Comment: I hope you understand that `prev = &curr` will *always* assign the same address (the address *of* `curr`, not the address *held* by `curr`) to `prev`, whether in a loop or not, no matter what the pointer value held by `curr`.Is this supposed to be a single-linked list that you're inserting a new node upon (middle, head, tail, makes no difference) ? Honestly, I don't think you need `prev` in this *at all*.

Comment: Academically I understand that.  This is pretty new ground for me, so I'm sort stumbling through this.  Yes, the type of curr is Block*.  The address this information is stored is constant.  I probably don't need double refs here, just having a hard time coming up with something that works.

Comment: Changing prev to just a pointer and judicious use of ifs got this thing to work.  Going to close this, I didn't need double refs...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just want this:

```
Block* curr = head;
Block* prev = NULL;
while (curr)
{
    prev = curr;
    curr = curr->next;
}
if (prev)
{
    prev->next = newBlock;
}
else
{
   head = newBlock;
}
newBlock->next = NULL;
```

Comment: This was probably closest to my needs, accepting this.